# Trying to connect neo4j with c# and run a query

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, neo4j, cypher

Im expirementing with databases and most recently specifically with the graph-database Neo4J. Im trying to connect Neo4j with C#, just as what I did with postgreSQL (see code)

```
    class Sql_connection : DatabaseConnection
{
    public string Server, Port, User_Id, Password, Database, Connstring;
    public NpgsqlConnection SQLconnection;

    public Sql_connection(string Server, string Port, string User_Id, string Password, string Database)
    {
        this.Server = Server;
        this.Port = Port;
        this.User_Id = User_Id;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Database = Database;
        this.Connstring = "Server="+this.Server+";Port="+this.Port+";User Id="+this.User_Id+";Password="+this.Password+";Database="+this.Database /*   +";"   */;
        this.SQLconnection = new NpgsqlConnection(this.Connstring);
        this.SQLconnection.Open();
    }


    public string InsertQuery(string INSERT_INTO, string VALUES)
    {
        NpgsqlCommand InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand();
        InsertCommand.Connection = this.SQLconnection;
        InsertCommand.CommandText = "insert into "+INSERT_INTO+" values "+VALUES;
        InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        return "succes";
    }
```

I already typed "Install-Package Neo4j.Driver-1.0.2" in the NuGetPackagemanager.
Besides that, I of course did some research myself, but I found multiple websites and github-repositories all saying something different, and I dont know what to believe/do anymore.

My two concrete questions are:
1: "How do you make a Neo4J-C# connection?"
2: "How do you run a query with this library/API"

I am aware of how graph-databases work and the syntax of Neo4j, so I understand the insertquery will not have insert into and values as key words.

Thanks in advance to everyone trying to help :D

Comment: There are plenty of examples alongside the Neo4j .NET Bolt driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j has good official documentation. Out of all sources the developers should be the most trustworthy. This is straight from their website and seems to work fine.

```
using Neo4j.Driver.V1;

using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.Basic("Username", "Password")))
using (var session = driver.Session()) {
    sesion.Run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})");
    var result = session.Run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title");

    foreach (var record in result)
        Console.WriteLine($"{record["title"].As<string>()} {record["name"].As<string>()}");
}
```

Taken from here : https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/

Simply replace the **localhost** with your server ip (or localhost if you run it locally) and the **username** and **password** with your own username and password.

The developers have given multiple links to examples both documentation and Github source code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and it worked. I didnt suspect making a connection would be so easy. Postgres uses more classes. Again, thanks for helping :)

Comment: @BornToGrill  I am getting an error like 'The token supplied to the function is invalid', 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception'  I used exactly the same code as you have given except changed the server "bolt://127.0.0.1" and username and password. Please help. I am new to this Neo4j,